# Multiple drag and drop image javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I make this code run multiple drag and drop?

I know that in jquery it uses 'each function', but I don't know how to do that in js. I need the selector to become a class so it can use more than 1 object, not only 1 id. I got the tutorial from this site and already changed the

`document.getElementById("example");`
to
`document.getElementsByClassName("example");`

However, I haven't yet succeeded due to this >

> Uncaught TypeError: droparea.addEventListener is not a function

Any suggestions?

[DRAG AND DROP IMAGE](https://cube3x.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-image-preview-using-html5/)

[FIDDLE HERE >>](http://jsfiddle.net/qjv6c2zg/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 left">
            <div class="filedroparea">(Drag & drop file here)</div>
            <img class="previewimage" alt="Preview Image" />
        </div>
        <!-- .left -->
        <div class="col-xs-8 center">
            <div class="box-wrap">
                <div class="box-ads-1">
                    <div class="filedroparea">(Drag & drop file here)</div>
                    <img class="previewimage" alt="Preview Image" />
                </div>
                <div class="box-ads-2">
                    <div class="filedroparea">(Drag & drop file here)</div>
                    <img class="previewimage" alt="Preview Image" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .center -->
        <div class="col-xs-2 right">
            <div class="filedroparea">(Drag & drop file here)</div>
            <img class="previewimage" alt="Preview Image" />
        </div>
        <!-- .right -->
    </div>
    <!-- .row -->
</div>
<!-- .container -->
    if (window.FileReader) {
    // Current browser supports drag and drop
    var droparea = document.getElementsByClassName("filedroparea");
    droparea.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
    droparea.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
    droparea.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

    var showButton = document.getElementsByClassName("showdroparea");
    showButton.addEventListener("click", showarea, false);
} else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('filedroparea').innerHTML = 'Your browser does not support FileReader HTML5 API';
}

// Event callback functions
function dragenter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get list of dropped files
    var dt = e.dataTransfer;
    var images = dt.files;

    // Reading first file
    var image = images[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);

    reader.addEventListener("loadend", showPreview, false);
}

function showPreview(e, file) {
    var imageElement = document.getElementsByClassName('previewimage');
    imageElement.src = this.result;

    document.getElementsByClassName("filedroparea").style.display = 'none';
    imageElement.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByClassName("showdroparea").style.display = 'block';
}

function showarea(e) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("filedroparea").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByClassName('previewimage').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName("showdroparea").style.display = 'none';
}

.filedroparea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
}
.previewimage {
    display:none;
}
.showdroparea {
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me. I attach one image and it was shown. Then I attach 2 images and only the last image was shown. I think your problem is this, but the error that you are saying doesn't show for me.

Comment: Hello, that's basic code, here's what i modify https://jsfiddle.net/qjv6c2zg/ @marcos-pérez-gude

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a bundle of elements, not only one. So you will receive `droparea[0]; droparea[1]` etc depending on the number of the dropareas you have. You must to iterate with a loop through all of the elements that returns the method and it will work

Comment: Yes, i think so, but i'm not js expert, so just a bit confused where part to iterate, thanks @marcos-pérez-gude

Comment: Your code will also break on showButton.addEventListener because you don't have any element with className = showdroparea in your HTML part.

Comment: Already remove that unnecessary class, but still not working @parkash-kumar

Comment: It won't work in current condition. If you will resolve droparea.addEventListener issue, you will observe issue with showPreview method.